# Why is current_date not a method but why is version a method in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am going through mysql tutorial https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html

and came across

```
select version(), current_date
```

May I know what makes version as method and current_date not as a method?

What imposes mysql to have different syntaxes for version and current_date?

Comment: they are not different select version(), current_date()  works as well is is only a shortcut

Comment: As a historical note, the practice of supplying empty parentheses for functions with no arguments comes from C and its predecessors. Pascal and Algol and Fortran don't have it, for example. So from that point of view `CURRENT_DATE` could still be a function. NB SQL is not object-oriented and doesn't have methods.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, `current_date` is a function which takes no arguments.

```
select current_date;
```

> 1) The s CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, and
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP respectively return the current date, current
>               time, and current timestamp; the time and timestamp values are
>               returned with time zone displacement equal to the current time
>               zone displacement of the SQL-session.

The grammar defines it as being called with no parens, in contrast to the optional parens on `current_time` and `current_timestamp`.

```
     <current date value function> ::= CURRENT_DATE

     <current time value function> ::=
            CURRENT_TIME [ <left paren> <time precision> <right paren> ]


     <current timestamp value function> ::=
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [ <left paren> <timestamp precision> <right paren> ]
```

It is a SQL reserved word; it cannot be used as a bare column name, so `current_date` is unambiguously a function call.

MySQL extends this by also allowing parens.

```
select current_date();
```

---

`version()` is a MySQL extension. It is not a reserved word. It's not even a MySQL keyword. The parens are required to avoid ambiguity with a column named "version".

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.19    |
+-----------+

mysql> select version;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'version' in 'field list'
```